# PHP-generated table column data not in proper spot?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have some PHP code which:

1. connects to mysql table
2. retrieves results
3. formats results for display as HTML table (add tags, etc)
4. stores the properly formatted results into a var named $echoResultsFinal

Then, inside of the HTML, I have some inline PHP. it:

1. checks to see if $echoResultsFinal isset
2. if it is, echo's out its contents
3. if not, echos out some stuff unrelated to the question

**The problem:** When the PHP generated table is echoed out, the table contents are not in the proper order.

The code which generates the table:

```
$echoResultArray = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $td = '';
    foreach(array('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'RIT_ACC', 'LINK_1', 'LINK_2', 'LINK_3', 'LINK_4', 'LINK_5', 'LINK_6' ) as $key => $value)
    {
        $td .= "<td>" . $row[$key] . "</td>";
    }
    $echoResultArray[$i] = "<tr>" . $td . "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
//Table closing tag
$echoResultsClosing = "</tbody></table>";
mysql_close();

$echoResultData = '';
foreach($echoResultArray as $var)
{
    $echoResultData .= $var;
    $echoResultData .= PHP_EOL;
}

$echoResultFinal = $echoResult . $echoResultData . $echoResultsClosing;
```

Any idea what's up? :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'not in the proper order'? Is it all blank? Half the columns missing? Coming through in a different order each time?

Comment: @andrewsi sorry for not making it clearer, by 'not in the proper order', I mean it is coming through in a different order each time. All of the data is there, however it is not placed into the table correctly.. ex first name is where account name is, last name is someplace random, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in your first `foreach` loop. The code you have is this:

```
foreach(array('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'RIT_ACC', 'LINK_1', 'LINK_2', 'LINK_3', 'LINK_4', 'LINK_5', 'LINK_6' ) as $key => $value)
{
    $td .= "<td>" . $row[$key] . "</td>";
}
```

The important thing to note here is that your foreach is assigning all the keys to `$key` and all of the values to `$value` as it iterates through the array you passed it (`$key => $value`). The problem here is you are using the `$key` to retrieve values from the `$row` array. However, with the array passed in, the keys are the numbers 0-8 (the indices of the array). You can see this by doing a `var_dump` of the array you pass to foreach:

```
array(9) {
  [0] => string(10) "FIRST_NAME"
  [1] => string(9) "LAST_NAME"
  [2] => string(7) "RIT_ACC"
  [3] => string(6) "LINK_1"
  [4] => string(6) "LINK_2"
  [5] => string(6) "LINK_3"
  [6] => string(6) "LINK_4"
  [7] => string(6) "LINK_5"
  [8] => string(6) "LINK_6"
}
```

The `$key`s that you are using are in brackets. So you are looking for numeric indexes in the `$row` array. This still gives you output because of the default behavior of [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-array):

> The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. **By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.** Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

I've added the emphasis here to the quote from the docs.

So your call to `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array with column names and values as well as a numeric index of the columns and their values. Your results were out of order because your query's `SELECT` ordered the fields in a different order than in the array you passed to foreach. Since the numeric index would correspond to the order of the fields in the `SELECT`, you were outputting them in the order the database gave them to you rather than the order you wanted.

To avoid this bug in the future, explicitly use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_row()` or pass the `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM` constants to `mysql_fetch_array()`. *However,* the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated and will be removed in PHP 5.4. I highly suggest you look into [PDO](http://php.net/PDO). (PDO has a similar return strategy which returns the column names and indices like `MYSQL_BOTH` so be careful!)

To fix this, you should be using the `$value` to get the column from the query because this variable will contain the string name of the columns.

```
foreach(array('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'RIT_ACC', 'LINK_1', 'LINK_2', 'LINK_3', 'LINK_4', 'LINK_5', 'LINK_6' ) as $value)
{
    $td .= "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>";
}
```

Also note that I changed your `as $key => $value` to just `as $value` because if you don't use the key, you don't need to specify a variable to receive it. Those are the [two forms of `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: All I can say is WOW. Not ONLY did you show me how to fix my problem, you also explained everything in a fantastic way a person new to PHP (me) can understand. This was a godly reply. Thank you so much! You should become a teacher. :)

Comment: @TomC Glad I could help! :) I hope your experiences with PHP are as good as those here on SO!